# How to use Controllers in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got a very basic page with a controller, I think it should be pretty obvious what I'm trying to do from the code, but it isn't working.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>{{ 800 / 40 }} </h1>
    <h1 ng-controller="MainController">{{message}}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the following in script.js

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
     $scope.message = "Hello";
});
```

The 800 / 40 is displaying 20, so that suggests the Angular script and ng-app is fine, but the  value of message isn't being set. In the example the ng-controller is in a h1 tag, but I have also tried it in a div which wraps around the h1.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You should [read the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) instead of just defining something somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an angular module

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('MainController', function($scope){
  $scope.message= "Hello";

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <h1 ng-controller="MainController">{{message}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a Angular module and place that module name for ng-app attribute.

Working solution: https://jsbin.com/nugipinale/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Define angular controller as

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
$scope.message = "Hello";
});
```

Comment: Probably because `app` is undefined.

Comment: Where does your `app` comes from ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
   <h1>{{ 800 / 40 }} </h1>
  <h1 >{{message}}</h1>
 </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "John";
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like this,

## Html code

```
 <html>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
   <h1>{{ 800 / 40 }} </h1>
  <h1 >{{message}}</h1>
 </div>
 </html>
```

## add this in Script file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "John";
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Please try with new

Comment: @RajuDetroja No it doesn't: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myapp' is not available!`. You have to use `module('myapp', [])` to define the module first.

Comment: Here , i changed and add full code (html and script code)